# Why do I get an uninitialised variable warning when I nest these two gcc statement expressions?

Tags: c, clang, compiler-warnings

I tried using gcc statement expressions to implement ctype functions. The following two statement expressions work perfectly individually, but fail when they are combined:

This works fine:

```
#define islower(a)              \
({                              \
    __typeof__(a) _a = (a);     \
    (_a >= 'a') && (_a <= 'z'); \
})
```

This works fine:

```
#define toupper(a)              \
({                              \
    __typeof__(a) _a = (a);     \
    ((_a >= 'a') && (_a <= 'z')) ? (_a - 'a' + 'A') : _a;   \
})
```

This **doesn't** work fine:

```
#define toupper(a)              \
({                              \
    __typeof__(a) _a = (a);     \
    islower(_a) ? (_a - 'a' + 'A') : _a;    \
})
```

gcc didn't mind this, but Clang yielded the following (on C Playground online):

```
/cplayground/code.cpp:21:51: warning: variable '_a' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]
        printf("%c -> %c" "\r\n", (char) i, (char)toupper(i));
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
/cplayground/code.cpp:13:13: note: expanded from macro 'toupper'
    islower(_a) ? (_a - 'a' + 'A') : _a;        \
    ~~~~~~~~^~~
/cplayground/code.cpp:6:25: note: expanded from macro 'islower'
    __typeof__(a) _a = (a);             \
                  ~~    ^
```

The practical fix is to edit the macros so that they don't both use _a as their variable name, i.e.

```
#define toupper(a)              \
({                              \
    __typeof__(a) _b = (a);     \
    islower(_b) ? (_b - 'a' + 'A') : _b;    \
})
```

So, even though both statement expressions superficially seem "watertight", clearly there is some kind of name scope leakage going on between the two that is messing things up, i.e. whereby the _a from the inner statement expression is affecting the _a in the outer statement expression.

If this is correct, it seems to imply that there's some kind of scope issue with variable naming inside statement expressions when you nest two, i.e. it's not quite as local as you think it is.

Is there a correct (or better, or more defensive) way of writing statement expressions that doesn't fall foul of this problem? Or is it just an unavoidable consequence of the way statement expressions work? i.e. "never use statement expressions inside other statement expressions"?

Comment: Please post _full_ [MCVE], including a short `main` and some `#include`s. `toupper(i)` - is `i` iniitialized?

Comment: It seems to work without any problem with BOTH gcc and clang on my env. Maybe specify the exact compiler version + compilation flags + add the full code you try?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when the macro argument name happens to be the same as the variable name declared within the statement-expression, you end up initialising the variable with itself.  This is no different from declaring:

```
int x = x;
```

Since you are not above using non-standard extensions, you can take advantage of `__COUNTER__` to mitigate this problem:

```
#define __isilet_impl(i, x) ({ \
        __auto_type _x ## i = (x); \
        ('A' <= _x ## i && _x ## i <= 'F') || ('a' <= _x ## i && _x ## i <= 'f'); \
    })
#define __isilet_impl0(i, x) __isilet_impl(i, x)
#define isilet(x) __isilet_impl0(__COUNTER__, x)

#define __toilet_impl(i, x) ({ \
        __auto_type _x ## i = (x); \
        isilet(_x ## i) ? _x ## i : 'F'; \
    })
#define __toilet_impl0(i, x) __toilet_impl(i, x)
#define toilet(x) __toilet_impl0(__COUNTER__, x)
```

A sufficiently determined user may still manage to break your macro, but it will be much harder.  (Sorry, this isn’t Lisp.  There is no `gensym`.)